# Is setting a "Master Password" essential for security of Thunderbird accounts?

Tags: thunderbird

On a single user machine with full disk encryption, is there a security advantage to using Thunderbird's Master Password, or is it safe to leave it disabled?

Without enabling the Master Password, could something like surfing the web potentially reveal the passwords for the e-mail accounts in Thunderbird? or is Master Password intended more as a protection for accounts on a multi-user computer?

Answer (score 2):

**Once you boot** other people with physical access to the computer or hackers making use of any vulnerabilities in the system *could* get access to your saved passwords. So it makes sense to encrypt them via master password anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think none of your hypoteses is correct. Master Password is only a convenience to not to enter several password if you have configured several account on Thunderbird: with a Master Password you only need to enter a unique password to unlock all accounts.

Moreover, you can get a reduced security with Master Password, because Thunderbird need to save all of your password somewhere. Don't worry, anyway, I am sure it uses strong encryption using your Master Password as a passphrase.